# Trying to download horses or human data but got ERROR 400 Scheme missing?

Tags: zip

!wget --no-check-certificate \
https://storage.googleapis.com \
  /laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/horse-or-human.zip \
  -O /tmp/horse-or-human.zip

Answer (score 0):

I looked for "wget scheme missing" and found this link - https://askubuntu.com/questions/758080/getting-scheme-missing-error-with-wget

Based on it I added simple quotes around the link and it worked:

```
!wget --no-check-certificate 'https://storage.googleapis.com/laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/horse-or-human.zip' \
-O /tmp/horse-or-human.zip
```